# Reading whole HTML in java

Tags: java, download

I have to collect informations hidden in whole html code of some websites. The problem is I can't read whole html code of those website. I tried jsoup, HTTPClient by Apache, HTTPClient java 7 version and latest java HTTPClient. Current (last of these) option works the best by showing 3098 lines of html code. Whole doc have ~1000 more lines.

Method responsible for downloading the page:

```java
public static boolean saveMaterials(String link, String filePath) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(link)).build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        try {
            PrintWriter tmp = new PrintWriter(filePath);
            tmp.print(response.body());
            return true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Do anybady have some idea how to change buffer size or other way of solving the problem?

Comment: Do you have a curl or wget command that can download the whole page?

Comment: An example would help.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Andersen, curl works great

Comment: Sorry Mr.Bourque I lost doc while doing curl version

Answer (score 0):

As Mr.Andersen suggested I used curl command:

```
static public boolean save(String link, String filePath) throws IOException {
    String command = "curl -X GET " + link;
    try (InputStream inputStream = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "))
            .directory(new File("/"))
            .start()
            .getInputStream();
         OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath, false)) {
        inputStream.transferTo(output);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```